# window.onload won't call and won't create a `<base>` tag

Tags: javascript, html, google-chrome

I have this html page with js embedded in it

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
  <title>Versions: 1.0.715 vs. 1.0.715 [ route HISTORIC_TIME ]</title>

  <head>
    <script type="script">
function createBase() {
  var str1 = window.location.href; 
  alert("check"); 
  var base = document.createElement('base'); 
  base.href = str1; 
  document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0].appendChild(base);
} 
window.onload = createBase;
    </script>
  </head>

  <body style="">
    <div class="content-background" style="background-color: #4285f4;   height: 398px;   position: absolute;   width: 100%;   top: 60px; z-index: -1;"></div>

  </body>

</html>
```

I try to add a `<base>` tag with the current url. However I refresh the page and the alert is not shown plus the `<base>` tag isn't created.

Why is that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> ```
> <script type="script">
> ```

`script` is not a registered mime type. It is not a programming language supported by any browser that I'm aware of. Since the browser don't know the language, it doesn't try to execute it.

The correct mime type for JavaScript is `application/javascript` (or `text/javascript` for legacy browsers).

As of HTML 5, the `type` attribute is optional and should be omitted entirely when writing JavaScript (since it is a waste of bytes and offers the opportunity to break code with typos).